# sum or substract an array conditionally?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with this code

I have to sum some digits and rest other

for example

```
const allData = [
{name: "comfort" ,notes: [7, 6, 1, 4, 5 ]},
{name: "speed", notes: [3, ,1 , 5, 6, 7]}
]
```

and we need to obtain the result of this data at this form

[0.1 , 0.7 ]

We obtain this result with this formula

((6+7)-(4+3+2+1))/(1+2+3+4+5+6+7)

first, we need to add all 6 or 7 of notes, the add all 4, 3, 2, or 1 of notes, then subtract this 2 values. And last, we have to divide them in the sum of all notes

I tried to reduce, but I do not how to continue

```
allData.forEach(notes => notes.notes = notes.notes.reduce((a, v) => ( a + v)  ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `reduce` in the following way:

```js
const allData = [{name: "comfort", notes: [7, 6, 1, 4, 5]}, {name: "speed", notes: [3, , 1, 5, 6, 7]}];
allData.forEach(notes => {
  notes.val = notes.notes.reduce((a, v) => (v > 5 ? a + v : a - v));
  //if you need to ignore 5
  //notes.val = notes.notes.reduce((a, v) => (v > 5 ? a + v : v < 5 ? a - v : a));
  notes.sum = notes.notes.reduce((a, v) => (a + v));
});

console.log(allData.map(notes => notes.val / notes.sum));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the basic code first

```
function getMagicResult(nodes) {
    const moreThanFive = nodes.filter((node) => node > 5);
    const lessThanFive = nodes.filter((node) => node < 5);
    const sum = nodes.reduce((total, node) => node + total, 0);

    return (moreThanFive - lessThanFive) / sum;
}
```

Then you can start building shorter code

```
function getMagicResult(nodes) {
    const fractionTop = nodes.reduce((total, node) => node > 5 ? total + node : total - node, 0);
    const fractionBottom = nodes.reduce((total, node) => node + total, 0);

    return fractionTop / fractionBototm;
}
```

You should start with basic code before making it one-line. This code is quite small and optimising it will not get lots of advantages